# Mysql security queries php

Tags: php, mysql, crash

I'm sorry for the title it might not make good sense to the content.

I've created a code where a query loads to db and selects some rows, then it makes a loop and puts it in an array.

```
SELECT----      
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $info[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

So this query is really easy and fast.

Now these queries is being done when a visitor enters a certain site in the web.
It all works great, but I never want to trust my visitors.
What if they updated the page several times (with multiple browsers,bots and so on)
Then my queries per second will increase very much. This might lead to a crash! Or can it?

So what I wonder is, how can I get the content, but still not letting the user update the page to many times a second. Cookies check last db connect?  Got any ideas for me ? Any advices?

Comment: You should look into caching.

Comment: If the content is non-specific to a certain user you could just run the query every 30sec and store the results. Then you use these results to display to the users.

Comment: thanks thats a great idea wonder why i never thought about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It normally works this way:

```
  define('THIRTY_SECONDS', 30);

  if (current_request_cache_time_in_seconds() < THIRTY_SECONDS) {
      get_request_response_from_cache();
  } else {
      get_request_response_from_php_code();
      save_request_response_to_cache();
  }
```

As you can see, this is a high-level function meaning that the actual code being executed is controlled on. In this example, the code for a specific page will only be executed once per 30 seconds (unless a race-condition appears).